# How can I install Deja Dup series 24 in Precise 12.04?

Tags: deja-dup

The integrity check in series 24 and above is important to me.

I asked the question on Launchpad as well: https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/219779

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any backport of version 24 for 12.04. Looking at the source, there's no `README` or guide, but it seems pretty standard. Perhaps a `./configure; make; make install` would suffice?